# Scrapy Crawling Rules Send URL

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, rules

i have a CrawlerSpider with my start_urls array:

```
    start_urls=[
            'http://www.tottus.cl/tottus/productListFragment/Conservas/118.8?No=0&Nrpp=&currentCatId=118.8',
            'http://www.tottus.cl/tottus/productListFragment/Alimento-Gato/9.2?No=0&Nrpp=&currentCatId=9.2'
        ]
```

And my Crawling Rules

```
rules = (      
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="next"]')),follow=True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="title"]/a')),callback='parse_item',process_links='process_value'),
)
```

I have a procces_links function, which receives a value (children url) and it make a X process and return it:

```
    def process_value(self,value):
    for link in value:
        #whatever procces
        link.url = link.url+'&categoria=hola'
        yield link
```

This is all with the children URL of start_urls.
start_urls array (parent url),  url in Rule (children url)

My problem is, i need send the parent url (start_url), to procces_value function. i need this:

```
def process_value(self,value):
    print(parent_url) #start_url . how i pass this in the Craw Rule?
    for link in value:
        print(link) #children url
```

How I can pass the parent url (start_url) to the function in my Rule?

Comment: You cannot get the parent URL there. But can you rather explain what you want to use the parent URL for inside that function? Maybe there is a different way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hi, I solved this. I wanted to send a personal parameter into the parent URL to the function and concatenate this to children URL. EJ: parentURL: www.domain.com/parentUrl&x=personalparameter. childrenURL: www.domain.com/parentUrl/childrenUrl?x=personalparemeter (concat)

i solved this with other "proccess_links"  function in the Crawling Rule, and concatenating the parameter